# Seaborn split violin plot not splitting properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I am trying to make a split violin plot but the plot is never actually split when generated. I have tried following the [seaborn guide](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html) but I'm not sure what is wrong since it does not produce a 2 colored split violin like in the guide.

My DF looks like this:

```
       Accuracy  Train_Time Model
0  0  0.825165  170.013132  LSTM
1  1  0.849305  171.778840  LSTM
2  2  0.826628  174.107146  LSTM
3  3  0.834674  176.774985  LSTM
4  0  0.927944   18.521901   CNN
5  1  0.929042   18.595950   CNN
6  2  0.930139   18.421983   CNN
7  3  0.927213   18.329449   CNN
```

And my seaborn plot code looks like this:

```
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
ax = sns.violinplot(y="Accuracy", hue="Model", data=comp_df, palette="Set2", split=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hue`-nesting can only be used *in addition* to a `x`. In your case, you need to create a dummy column with the same value for the whole dataset.

```
comp_df['dummy'] = 0
ax = sns.violinplot(y="Accuracy", x='dummy', hue="Model", data=comp_df, palette="Set2", split=True)
```